# How to use SweetAlert in ionic 2 with Angular2?

Tags: angular, ionic2, alert

swal(
  'Good job!',
  'You clicked the button!',
  'success'
)

I want to use this type of swal alert in my ionic app using angular 2  Can anyone guide?

Comment: Read the https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/

Answer (score 2):

There's a sweet alert module available for angular 2

https://github.com/seiyria/ng2-sweetalert2

```
import { SweetAlertService } from 'ng2-sweetalert2';

@Component({
  providers: [SweetAlertService]
})
export class MyComponent {

  static get parameters() {
    return [[SweetAlertService]];
  }

  constructor(swal) {
    this.swalService = swal;
  }
```

This will work when sweetalert2.min.css loaded up.

**EDIT Sept:2017**

This is **DEPRECATED** as of August 2017

You should use https://github.com/toverux/ngsweetalert2 or https://www.npmjs.com/package/sweetalert2

Comment: Buddy, this thing was deprecated in  Aug 6, 2017 & i posted my answer on Feb 24 2017.!!!!

Comment: no doubt, it declare's variables so it does not fail in angular compilation, but thats not the reason to downvote

Comment: yes I know for that I say I'm sorry I can't upvote now because : 
You last voted on this answer 45 mins ago. Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited.

Comment: mentioned the deprecation fact and other alternatives that can be used